# Logic Thinking Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

So basing on the idea that:

> Every man is mortal.
>
> Socrates is a man.
>
> So, Socrates is mortal.

In Prolog:

```
man(socrates).
mortal(X) :- man(X).
```

My question is... what's the equivalent to the above for:

> Every student loves work.
>
> This is work.
>
> Therefore, I love this work.

I know this is beginner stuff, I'm just having an issue with the logical thinking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Every student loves work. This is work. Therefore, i love this work.

This requires the fact that you are a student, which you do not claim.

Since your triplet is missing the logical link, there are (at least) two options to complete it:

**1.**

```
Every student loves work.
I am a student.
Therefore I love work.
```

**2.**

```
Every student loves work.
This is work.
Therefore every student loves it.
```